# Prove heap property (subset and equality) in Separation Logic using Coq

Tags: logic, heap, coq

I want to prove two Lemmas in coq to be useful for further proofs. I have already thought these for several hours (>= 4 hours). I want to get some hints or partial or complete proofs about lemmas below. (These lemmas are about separation logic.)

```
Lemma imply_subset: forall (h1 h2 h: heap), 
  h_union h1 h2 = h -> disjoint h1 h2 -> h_subset h2 h.
Proof.
  Admitted.

Lemma heap_equality1: forall (h1 h2 h h11: heap),
  disjoint h1 h2 -> disjoint h11 h2 -> 
    h_union h1 h2 = h -> h_union h11 h2 = h -> h1 = h11.
Proof.
  Admitted.
```

Below are some definitions.

```
(* if heap maps a natural number (address) to
None, we say the address is not a valid address,
or it is not in the domain of the heap *)

Definition heap := nat -> option nat.

(* h1 and h2 have disjoint domain *)
Definition disjoint (h1 h2: heap) : Prop := 
  forall l, not_in_dom l h1 \/ not_in_dom l h2.

(* union of two heaps *)
Definition h_union (h1 h2: heap) : heap :=
  fun l => 
    if (in_not_in_dec l h1) then h1 l else h2 l.

(* h1 is a subset of h2 *)
Definition h_subset (h1 h2: heap) : Prop := 
  forall l n, h1 l = Some n -> h2 l = Some n.
```

Comment: I think this problem is concerned with how to prove function equality. Maybe need to use Axiom functional_extensionality in Coq.

Comment: The first one doesn't need functional extensionality (the second does). After substituting `h`, and unfolding a bit, you can destruct `in_not_in_dec l h1`, the first case should be contradictory, and the second should be trivial.

Comment: Also, the statement of the second one can be simplified into `disjoint h1 h -> h_union h1 h = h_union h2 h -> h1 = h2`